# Can anyone recommend a textbook like Precalculus by Carl Stitz and Jeff Zeagar for topics in Linear Algebra and Calculus?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

This October I should start my bachelor's in mathematical-technical software development at FernUniversität in Hagen, Germany. Since German is my 2nd foreign language (English is my 1st), I'd like to know if there are any books that cover the topics of Linear Algebra and Calculus/Analysis in a similar format that of Precalculus written by Carl Stitz and Jeff Zeagar? Mainly, the format is that there is a lot of text and nuanced explanations (many dislike this), plus plenty of problems.

The goal is to primarily use German textbooks and course material to study, but when and if necessary, I want to have something that I can fall back onto to gain more lucid understanding, at least for the first few modules until I become more comfortable with the German language.

Here is the link to Carl Stitz's and Jeff Zeagar's website where you can find links to their open-source pdfs: https://www.stitz-zeager.com/

Thanks a lot.

Best regards.

Comment: I am not familiar with the author but there is an email link at the bottom of the link you provided. Why not reach out and tell him how much you enjoyed the Precalculus book and ask if he has any suggestions? He may have some lecture notes he'd be willing to share.

Comment: Right... That's a good idea, I will try it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if they have the format you are looking for, but here are some free mathematics textbooks for Linear Algebra and Calculus:

Linear Algebra by Jim Hefferon:
http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/

Interactive Linear Algebra by Dan Margalit and Joseph Rabinoff:
https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/index.html
*contains no questions

Calculus by Strang:
https://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-18-001-calculus-online-textbook-spring-2005/textbook/

Elementary Calculus: An Infinitesimal Approach by Kiesler:
[https://people.math.wisc.edu/~keisler/calc.html](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Ekeisler/calc.html)